# How to include "out of stock" products in GraphQL results

Tags: magento2.4, graphql

I tried to query products in Magento 2 GraphQL using the bellow query, but the results only shows "IN_STOCK" products:

```
{
  products(
    filter:
    {
      sku:
      {
        in: [
          "SKU_001",
          "SKU_002",
          "SKU_003"
        ]
      }
    }
  ) {
    items {
      name
      sku
      stock_status
      price_range {
        minimum_price {
          regular_price {
            value
            currency
          }
        }
      }
    }
    total_count
    page_info {
      page_size
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to set to "true" the *"Display out of stock products"* config in *Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options* and run a reindex but the results are the same.

Is there a way to query IN_STOCK and OUT_OF_STOCK products together?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the exact same problem. Cheers

Comment: @BenC I added an answer bellow... in my case it was only some settings done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. In my case, some properties were configured wrong, so I will post a checklist:

1. Set "Display out of stock products" flag true in **Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options > [Display Out of Stock Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbzvR.png)**
2. Enable the products you want to view in API (some of my products were disabled).
3. In product information, set "Manage Stock" true. You can view this setting in product edit page **Sources > Inventory > Advanced Inventory > [Manage Stock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH1R5.jpg)"**

That's it... now the API shows **OUT_OF_STOCK** products. If not, try to run a reindex before.

[GraphQl response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Tnpc.jpg)

Comment: Absolute legend! I missed the Display out of stock flag. Working perfectly for me now, thank you